# Real coefficient polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Could someone help about the proof way with

Let $ f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] $ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $f(a)=0$ then $ (x-a)$ | $f(x)$

Comment: I suppose you want $a$ to be an integer?

Comment: Yes yes sorry for missing part :'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this with the euclidean division :

1- You can notice that in the proof of the existence of the euclidean division for polynomials in a field, you don't use the fact that it's a field if the polynomial that you're dividing by is unitary.
2- Use the division in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

If you go along with 1., then you'll find $f(x) = (x-a)q(x) + r(x)$ where $deg(r)<1$, and evaluating in $a$ gives $r=0$.

If you go with 2., then you have $f(x) = (x-a)q(x)$, with $q\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. But then you can use Gauss's lemma to show that $q\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ actually, and that also gives you what you want

Answer (score 1):

Consider the polynomial $g(y) = f(y+a)$. Then $g(0) = f(a) = 0$.

Let us write $g$ as $g(y) = g_n y^n + \ldots g_1 y + g_0$ for some $g_i  \in \mathbb Z$.

Then we see that $g(0) = g_0$. With the equation from above we immediately see that $g_0=0$.

So $f(x) = g(x-a) = g_n (x-a)^n + \ldots + g_1 (x-a)^1 = (x-a)[g_n(x-a)^{n-1}+\ldots+g_1]$ and therefore $(x-a) \mid f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

by long division we can find a $g  \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying:
$$
f(x) = (x-a)g(x)+r
$$
substituting $x=a$ gives $r=0$. the result follows